# Can NP-Hard be converted to NP?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, complexity-classes, np

I get that all problems in NP can be reduced in polynomial time to some NP-Hard problem. An NP-Hard problem is also supposed to be harder or at least as hard as any NP problem.

Can an NP-Hard problem be reduced to an NP problem, which is not already an NP-Complete problem?

Also, are NP-Hard problems inter-convertible?

Comment: NP-hard problems aren't even necessarily in NP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture I always visualize for this is the one featured on [here on the Wikipedia page for **NP**-Completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). The definition of **NP**-Hard is that it is the set of problems to which all **NP** problems can be reduced in polynomial time, so, for example, the bounded halting problem - does a Turing Machine $M$ halt within $k$ steps, is strictly *not* in **NP**, because there is no way to check in polynomial time whether a Turing Machine halts in $k$ steps. However, all problems can be converted to the bounded halting problem very easily, simply by building a Turing Machine which ostensibly solves the problem and asking whether it halts in some appropriate amount of time.

This answers your first question: not all **NP**-Hard problems are in **NP** or can be reduced to them. As for the second: Some **NP**-Hard problems can be converted to one another. For example, the **EXP-TIME** class, which can be though of as the next class beyond **P**, has **EXP-TIME**-Complete problems just like **NP** has **NP**-Complete problems, and there are classes even beyond that, indefinitely.

Comment: "**EXP-TIME** [...] can be though of as the next class beyond **P**" Obviously, this is an informal statement which isn't supposed to be literally true but **NP**, **PSPACE** and all kinds of other natural classes sit between **P** and **EXP-TIME**. **EXP-TIME** isn't even the smallest class we know to strictly include **P**: for example, by the time hierarchy theorem, $\mathrm{P}\subsetneq\mathbf{TIME}[n^{O(\log n)}]\subsetneq\mathbf{EXP}$. Also, we don't actually know that **NP** and **EXP-TIME** are different, so an **EXP-time**-complete problem could still be **NP**-complete.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's true, it's only meant as a mental tool to help you get a hold on the complexity zoo. The reason I like to think of it way way is because it generalizes to __EXPTIME=TIME__ $\left(2^{f(n)}\right) \nsubseteq$ __2-EXPTIME=TIME__ $\left( 2^{2^{f(n)} } \right) \cdots \nsubseteq k-$ __EXPTIME__ , where in each class you take the union of all polynomial functions $f$. It's a nice first approximation of how hard these problems are, to which you can then relate the more subtle classes. Obviously, the more such tools, the better, so your comments are very helpful.

Comment: You mean $\subsetneq$, not $\not\subseteq$. :-) (`\subsetneq`)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, I meant $\subsetneq$, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, the diagram and the example in context help a lot!

Answer (score 3):

> Can an NP-Hard problem be reduced to an NP problem, which is not already an NP-Complete problem?

No. Suppose that $X$ is **NP**-hard and it reduces to $Y$. By definition of **NP**-hardness, every problem in **NP** reduces to $X$. By transitivity of reduction, every problem in **NP** also reduces to $Y$, so $Y$ is **NP**-hard.  Since $Y$ is postulated to be in **NP**, $Y$ is **NP**-complete.

> Also, are NP-Hard problems inter-convertible?

Not necessarily, no. **NP**-hard problems aren't even necessarily decidable: the halting problem is **NP**-hard, for example.

For more examples, consider the classes $k$-**EXP** for integers $k\geq 1$.  $1$-**EXP** is just **EXP** (exponential time, i.e., time $O(2^n)$), $2$-**EXP** is problems decidable in time $O(2^{2^n})$, $3$-EXP is triply-exponential $O(2^{2^{2^n}})$ and so on. By the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem), all of these classes are different, which means that a $k$-**EXP**-complete problem is not in $(k-1)$-**EXP**.  But a $k$-**EXP**-complete problem is certainly **NP**-hard because **NP**$\,\subseteq\,$**EXP**$\,\subseteq k$-**EXP**.  So, you can take an infinite sequence $X_1, X_2, \dots$ of problems where $X_i$ is $i$-**EXP**-complete for each $i$.  Each of these problems is **NP**-hard but $X_k$ is provably not reducible to $X_j$ for any $j<k$.